# How to correctly implement executor that runs multiple iterations and waits for all tasks to complete and successfully terminates after tasks are done

Tags: java, multithreading

**Cut to the chase short answer ---------------------**

Code demonstrating the accepted answer can be found here:

Full example:

https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/thread-example/tree/shutdown-first

Implementation:

https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/thread-example/blob/shutdown-first/src/main/java/com/nachc/examples/threadexample/WidgetFactory.java

**Original Post -------------------------------------**

There are a number of examples of use of Java threads and Executors:
https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-thread-pool-executor-example/

https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/thread-pools.html

https://xperti.io/blogs/thread-pools-java-introduction/

https://www.journaldev.com/1069/threadpoolexecutor-java-thread-pool-example-executorservice

https://stackify.com/java-thread-pools/

However, I've not been able to successfully write an example that executes all of the tasks, waits for the tasks to complete, and then correctly terminates.

Working from this example: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/java-thread-pool-executor-example/

The code only calls executor.shutdown().  This does not allow the threads time to complete if they consume any time.

I've created a complete simplest example here: https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/thread-example/tree/await-termination

The shutdown only branch covers this use case (https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/thread-example/tree/shutdown-only):

```
public void makeWidgets() {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(batchSize);
    log.info("Building " + howMany + " widgets...");
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
        Widget widget = new Widget(lotNumber, i);
        WidgetRunnable runnable = new WidgetRunnable(widget);
        executor.execute(runnable);
    }
    log.info("SHUTTING DOWN----------------");
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

This code gives the following output (there should be 1000 widgets created and they should report that they are done after waiting 1 second).

```
2022-04-23 21:27:05,796 21:27:05.796 [main] INFO  (WidgetFactoryIntegrationTest.java:12) - Starting test...
2022-04-23 21:27:05,799 21:27:05.799 [main] INFO  (WidgetFactory.java:29) - Building 100 widgets...
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/1
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/3
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/0
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/4
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-6] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/5
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-7] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/6
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-8] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/7
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-10] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/9
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-9] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/8
2022-04-23 21:27:05,801 21:27:05.801 [main] INFO  (WidgetFactory.java:35) - SHUTTING DOWN----------------
2022-04-23 21:27:05,800 21:27:05.800 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO  (Widget.java:24) - Starting build: 1/2
2022-04-23 21:27:05,801 21:27:05.801 [main] INFO  (WidgetFactoryIntegrationTest.java:18) - Done.
```

If I add executor.awaitTermination the code runs all threads but never terminates. This example is in the await-termination branch: https://github.com/NACHC-CAD/thread-example/tree/await-termination

```
public void makeWidgets() {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(batchSize);
    log.info("Building " + howMany + " widgets...");
    for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
        Widget widget = new Widget(lotNumber, i);
        WidgetRunnable runnable = new WidgetRunnable(widget);
        executor.execute(runnable);
    }
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch(Exception exp) {
        throw(new RuntimeException(exp));
    }
    log.info("SHUTTING DOWN----------------");
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

This code lets all of the runnables finish but never exits.  How do I let all of the runnables finish and have the code run to completion (exit)?

Comment: Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html. The awaitTermination() description reads 'Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request', while the shutdown() method description reads 'Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted'. Which point that awaitTermination is effective after a shutdown() call. Have not tested it, but I think you should call shutdown() first and then awaitTermination. Your code is calling awaitTermination and then shutdown

Comment: @Ironluca, Huzzah! That seems to do the trick.  Post as an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: glad that it helped, I have added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With reference to [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) documentation. The awaitTermination() method description reads:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request

While the shutdown() method descriptin reads

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted

Which indicates that awaitTermination() call is effective after a shutdown() call.

To solve the above problem, shutdown() needs to be called first and then awaitTermination()

*NOTE: I have not personally tested this; however, John has, as mentioned in the comment of the original post and the mechanism works*

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Ironluca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71988405/642706) is correct. Here is additional points and some example code.

For one thing, there is no need to declare & cast [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) directly. Just use the more general [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

And using a thread pool sized to your batch size seems unwise. In current Java, you generally want an active thread pool to be less than the count of CPU cores. (This calculus will change radically if [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) and its [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/425) succeeds, but that is not the reality today, though you can try the [early-access build](https://jdk.java.net/loom/).)

```
int threadPoolSize = 3 ;  // Generally less than number of cores. 
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( threadPoolSize );
```

Let's simplify your example scenario. We define `Widget` as a simple [record](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395).

```
record Widget ( UUID id , Instant whenCreated ) {}
```

Define a task that produces a `Widget`. We want to get back a `Widget` object, so we use `Callable` rather than `Runnable`.

```java
Callable < Widget > makeWidgetTask = ( ) -> {
    Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( 50 ).toMillis() ); // Pretend that we have a long-running task.
    Widget widget = new Widget( UUID.randomUUID() , Instant.now() );
    return widget;
};
```

Make a big collection, to be used in running that task many times.

```
List < Callable < Widget > > tasks = Collections.nCopies( 1_000 , makeWidgetTask );
```

Actually, we need to wrap in a try-catch.

```java
List < Future < Widget > > futures = null;
try
{
    futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks );
}
catch ( InterruptedException e )
{
    throw new RuntimeException( e );
}
```

Submit all those tasks to the executor service. Notice how we get back a list of [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) objects. A `Future` is our handle to the success or failure of each task’s completion.

As for how to wait for completion, and how to use `ExecutorService#shutdown`, `shutdownNow`, and `awaitTermination`, merely read the Javadoc.  A full example of boilerplate code is provided for you.

To quote the Javadoc:

```java
pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
try {
    // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
    if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
        pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
        // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
        if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
    }
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
    pool.shutdownNow();
    // Preserve interrupt status
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

The key concept is that `shutdown` does not stop any work-in-progress. All tasks currently under execution will continue. All submitted tasks will eventually be scheduled for execution on a core as a thread becomes available. The `shutdown` method does only one thing: Stop any further tasks from being submitted to this executor service. To quote the Javadoc:

> `shutdown()` … previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

To quote further:

> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use `awaitTermination` to do that.

So you need to call `awaitTermination` after calling `shutdown`. You pass arguments for a reasonable time in which you expect all submitted tasks to be completed or cancelled or interrupted. If that time limit elapses, then you can presume something has gone wrong.

Notice that the call to `shutdown` does *not* block, but the call to `awaitTermination` *does* block.

Let's adapt the boilerplate code to our own example.

```java
executorService.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted.
try
{
    if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
    {
        executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks.
        // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled.
        if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
        { System.err.println( "Executor service did not terminate." ); }
    }
}
catch ( InterruptedException ex )
{
    executorService.shutdownNow();  // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  // Preserve interrupt status
}
```

Finally, review our results by examining the collection of `Future` objects.

```java
System.out.println( "Count futures: " + futures.size() );
for ( Future < Widget > future : futures )
{
    if ( ! future.isDone() ) { System.out.println( "Oops! Task not done: " + future.toString() ); }
    else if ( future.isCancelled() ) { System.out.println( "Bummer. Task cancelled: " + future.toString() ); }
    else // Else task must have completed successfully.
    {
        try
        {
            Widget widget = future.get();
            System.out.println( widget.toString() );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
        catch ( ExecutionException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }
}
```

Add some elapsed time code at top and bottom.

```java
long start = System.nanoTime();
…
System.out.println( "Elapsed: " + Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start ) );
```

On my [M1 MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Fourth_generation_(13-inch,_M1,_2020)) with 8 real cores, on Java 18, that takes about 18 seconds.

```
Count futures: 1000
Widget[id=56e594bf-75a6-4cf1-83fc-2b671873c534, whenCreated=2022-04-25T07:00:18.977719Z]
Widget[id=11373948-0689-467a-9ace-1e8d57f40f40, whenCreated=2022-04-25T07:00:18.977721Z]
…
Widget[id=d3b11574-6c11-41cc-9f26-c24ad53aa18c, whenCreated=2022-04-25T07:00:36.747058Z]
Widget[id=017ff453-da92-4296-992e-2c2a2ac44ed8, whenCreated=2022-04-25T07:00:36.748571Z]
Elapsed: PT17.906065583S
```

---

Full example code, for your copy-paste convenience.

```java
package work.basil.example.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        int threadPoolSize = 3;  // Generally less than number of cores.
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( threadPoolSize );

        record Widget( UUID id , Instant whenCreated )
        {
        }

        Callable < Widget > makeWidgetTask = ( ) -> {
            Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( 50 ).toMillis() ); // Pretend that we have a long-running task.
            Widget widget = new Widget( UUID.randomUUID() , Instant.now() );
            return widget;
        };

        List < Callable < Widget > > tasks = Collections.nCopies( 1_000 , makeWidgetTask );

        List < Future < Widget > > futures = null;
        try
        {
            futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }

        executorService.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted.
        try
        {
            if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
            {
                executorService.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks.
                // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled.
                if ( ! executorService.awaitTermination( 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) )
                { System.err.println( "Executor service did not terminate." ); }
            }
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException ex )
        {
            executorService.shutdownNow();  // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();  // Preserve interrupt status
        }

        System.out.println( "Count futures: " + futures.size() );
        for ( Future < Widget > future : futures )
        {
            if ( ! future.isDone() ) { System.out.println( "Oops! Task not done: " + future.toString() ); }
            else if ( future.isCancelled() ) { System.out.println( "Bummer. Task cancelled: " + future.toString() ); }
            else // Else task must have completed successfully.
            {
                try
                {
                    Widget widget = future.get();
                    System.out.println( widget.toString() );
                }
                catch ( InterruptedException e )
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException( e );
                }
                catch ( ExecutionException e )
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException( e );
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println( "Elapsed: " + Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime() - start ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: About the number of threads being smaller than the number of cores: I'm mostly using this to download large amounts of data from a REST service, so most of the time for each thread is spent waiting for the server to respond, so having lots of threads does make a big difference.